# Kafka Streams leftJoin - Different behaviour between processing live vs replaying old messages

Tags: left-join, apache-kafka-streams

I am using KafkaStreams to make a leftJoin between 2 streams coming from 2 topics. I've set a JoinWindow (24h with 25h grace).

```
 topic_1 -->  KS1 -->  selectKey -->
                                     (LEFT_JOIN)  -->  KS3
                topic_2 -->  KS2 -->
```

During live all good, but when I replay all events from the beginning, the join is not resolved as before and I see lot of logs as following:

```
[warn] org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore [] - Skipping record for expired segment
```

If I set a huge JoinWindow, say 3 years, the problem is resolved but I can't afford it due to memory constraints.

Notice that I'm using a custom TimeExtractor with business event time.

I'd appreciate any kind of help. I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: How do you do the replay? Did you reset your application use `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh`? Or did you use `bin/kafka-consumer-group.sh`?

Comment: bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh

Comment: Hard to say. Which version are you using? Segment rolling is based on event-timestamps (ie, whatever TimestampExtractor returns) and thus the behavior should be the same on replay.